# Allow only Cloudflare IP into Netlify

Tags: ip, cloudflare, netlify

We use Cloudflare DNS. We setup a CNAME record to Netlify website (mywebsite.netlify.app).
How to allow only cloudflare proxy to connect to mywebsite.netlify.app ?

I would like to avoid the Netlify domain to be requested directly (as we can't delete it).

Comment: Hi Emilie, I'm having similar issues when using Cloudflare proxies.. At times I get a 500 server error because Netlify will block the many request coming from Cloudflare. I guess that allowing cloudflare proxies only in Netlify will stop them from doing it.
Have you found a solution to this already?

Comment: Hi @CarlosGregorio, my issue is that mywebsite.netlify.app could be directly accessible, as netlifty provide a "technical" subdomain. And you can't delete it. So if you can access mywebsite.netlify.app, you bypass Cloudflare, which is a security breach.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very recent release of Netlify Firewall which, I believe, will allow you to do what you want.

Please check below link

[Netlify Firewall Rules](https://www.netlify.com/blog/general-availability-web-application-firewall-traffic-rules/)

You can also find the Cloudflare IP ranges
[here](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/), but you probably already know that.

The caveat is that is only available in Netlify Enterprise plans. Not sure what plan are you on.

Maybe worth sending an email to netlify support to check if they can create some rules for you.

Hope this helps.